# Prolog: SLICE from list, why it fails so quickly?

Tags: prolog

```
iterate([],acc,K,L,ac):- length(acc,K),length(ac,K-L+1).

iterate([H|M], acc, K, L,[]):-  length(acc, X), X<K-1,  append( acc,  [H], New),
iterate(M, New, K, L, []).

iterate([H|M], acc, K, L,[]):-  length(acc, X), X=K-1,  append( acc,  [H], New), append([],[H],ac),
iterate(M, New, K, L, ac).

iterate([H|M], acc, K, L, ac):- length(acc, K), length(ac, X), X<K-L +1,
append(ac, [H], SLICE), iterate(M, acc, K, L, SLICE).

iterate([_|_], acc, K, L, SLICE) :- length(acc, K), length(SLICE, K-L+1).
```

I am trying to solve an online exercise, I  found. I don't want to look at the solution yet. The code above, doesn't work and when I tried to trace it I saw that it fails really early which I can't explain on my own.

```
   Call: (10) iterate([1, 2, 3, 4], [], 2, 4, _8428) ? creep
   Fail: (10) iterate([1, 2, 3, 4], [], 2, 4, _8428) ? creep
false.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `length(acc, X)` will always fail. And so does `X=K-1` with `X` an integer

Comment: And `acc` in general is a constant, you probably meant it being `Acc`

Comment: yes you are right about acc I changed it. Why length(acc,X) & ```X = K-1``` will always fail though?

Comment: Upon success of `length(Acc,X)`, `X` will be an integer, which is never the same as the **structure** `(-)/2`. In Prolog, `=` means syntactically equal not arithmetically equal.